# SSL on Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: server, 13.10, apache2, ssl

I am building an Ubuntu home server and would like to enable ssl for access via https.

I have attempted to follow [these instructions](http://www.unixmen.com/install-apache-ssl-ubuntu-13-10/) but when I try to enable ssl I get this error

```
ERROR: Site default-ssl not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf is a real file, not touching it
```

Does anyone have any idea's that might shed light on how I could resolve this?

Comment: Give us contents of default-ssl.conf!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue and resolved it.

I had followed the guide linked above which suggested this file needed to be edited:

*/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf*,

Actually it didn't exist - I though I had deleted it so I recreated it.

What I should have done was edited this file

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf*

Thats sorted it out